# JPA Hibernate - Mapping Embedded Collections to a Single Table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a table with lot of fields such as

Account

OrderNo

Term

**LegNo**

**LegSymbol**

**LegSymbolType**

**LegExchangeType**

etc etc

The primary key of the above table is a composite key comprising of Account, OrderNo & LegNo

The data in the DB would look  something like this

**1234**  **1** 2 **1** AAA BBB CCC

**1234**  **1** 2 **2** DDD EEE FFF

The bolded ones are Account,Order,LegNo respectively.

While designing the entity for the above table, we want to group all the Leg related information (All **bolded** columns ) in a separate class and all other info in a entity

So, the main Order Entity will contain the Embedded object Leg. (I assume Leg wont be defined as an entity since it is not a separate table as such).

```
@Entity
@Table(name="xxx")
public class Order implements Serializable {

    ... All order specific fields & it's getters/setters

}

@Embeddable
public class Leg implements Serializable {

  private long legNo;
  private String legSymbol;

  ...
  ...
}
```

I assume Order Entity would hold the account, orderNo,Term info and the OrderLeg embedded object would the other info like the above.

We can have multiple legs for the same order as shown in the above record. Hence we might need to have collection of legs inside the Order entity.

Can we achieve this functionality as we have only one table in place ? We cannot change the schema of the table or create a new table as it is out of our control.

I tried using the @ElementCollection in the Order Entity on List of Legs but it looks like, when I try to persist a new order, the Leg details are not being taken as part of the query.

If I have hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create as part of the persistence.xml, it deletes the existing schema and alters the existing order table to hold only the order infos and creates a separate leg table to hold the leg infos which is not desired.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="xxx")
public class Order implements Serializable {

**@ElementCollection
private List<Leg> a = new ArrayList<Leg>();**
}
```

The values set to Leg class such as LegNo, LegSymbol etc  is not included in the insert query at all and I always get an exception since the LegNo is a mandatory field in the table.

Please advise..

Comment: Do you have `@Embedded` on the `List<Leg>` entry? In addition to marking the `Leg`class `@Embeddable` you have to do that as well.

Comment: Also if you're using Hibernate as your provider I think the correct annotation for an embedded collection is `@CollectionOfElements` not `@ElementCollection`

Comment: You cannot store a collection of elements in a single record. You need a separate table.

Comment: @MagicMan: Yes, I tried with & without \@Embedded annotation on the List<Leg> entry . But it does not seem to work. and \@CollectionOfElements has been removed as of Hibernate 4 and \@ElementCollection has replaced it.   I was wondering whether I can achieve what i wanted and whether I am following the right approach.. Do I have to use some other annotation ?

Comment: @DavidLevesque: I am not trying to store all the collection values in a single record. The size of the collection corresponds to the no. of the rows in the table. The order attributes would however be the same for all these records. Only the leg attributes would vary which is reflected in the collections

Comment: Take a look at the hibernate docs on for this: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-ofvalues Also I'm not real clear about the `Leg` table definition; is it a separate table or just columns on the Order table?

Comment: @MagicMan: Legs are just columns in the order table. We have only one table at a DB level.. But from an entity perspective, we want to design a separate Order entity containing collection of leg info.. For a given Order, there would be multiple rows in the database with different leg info which is what we are trying to represent as a collection.